# Sender Authentication Package with Multiple domains

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to create a new Business Unit and as per the requirement,I am supposed to create 3 sub domains and 3 sender profiles for this Business Unit. My question is whether all these 3 sub domains will have the same IP address?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will all depend on what you have purchased.

A SAP will typically come with 1 IP Address. You can send emails from a SAP domain (being it's an authenticated domain)

You can additionally buy/register multiple private domains on the same business unit and again send emails from those private domains. These private domains can send from the same IP Address.

You can only have 1 SAP for a business unit, but you can have multiple private domains.

Equally, you can multiple IP addresses for a business unit.  Sending from an IP address will depend on many factors i.e. volumes, reputation etc. Typically you want to dedicate an IP address for transactional sends and the you could share you other IPs across the other sub domains.

You could alternatively dedicate an IP address per private domain, but it is a wider architectural decision and based on your brand, volumes and practice.

Comment: Adding a private domain does not allow for Link wrapping. Let's say that I already have 1 SAP configured with em1.mysite1.com. Now I want to purchase a private domain em2.mysite2.com in the Same Business  Unit . Does doing this will automatically wrap my links with em1.mysite1.com and will I be presented to change the link wrapping to private domain?